# Object Locations with Classes (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I print out my list of the top twenty occurrences all I get is the object location and not the actual data I need. Also if you have any ideas for improvement that would be greatly appreciated. Please help. Thanks.

Here is my code.

```
class topList():
    __slots__ = ( "name", "gender", "occurences" )

def mkList( name, gender, occurences ):
    find = topList()
    find.name = name
    find.gender = gender
    find.occurences = occurences
    return find

def main():
    year = input( 'Enter year: ' )
    file = open( 'yob' + year + '.txt' )
    lst = []
    femaleLst = []
    maleLst = []
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().split( "," )
        names = mkList( line[0], line[1], line[2] )
        lst.append( names )
        if names.gender == 'F':
            femaleLst += [ line ]
        else:
            maleLst += [ line ]
    while len( lst ) < 20:
        male = maleLst.pop()
        female = femaleLst.pop()
        if maleLst.occurences > femaleLst.occurences:
            lst += [ male ]
        else:
            lst += [ female ]
    print( lst[ : 20] )

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) methods to your class:

```
class topList():
    __slots__ = ( "name", "gender", "occurences" )

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'topList({s.name!r}, {s.gender!r}, {s.occurences!r})'.format(s=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{s.name} ({s.gender}): {s.occurences!r})'.format(s=self)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class topList():
...     __slots__ = ( "name", "gender", "occurences" )
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'topList({s.name!r}, {s.gender!r}, {s.occurences!r})'.format(s=self)
... 
>>> tl = topList()
>>> tl.name = 'FooBar'
>>> tl.gender = 'm'
>>> tl.occurences = 42
>>> print(tl)
FooBar (m): 42
>>> tl
topList('FooBar', 'm', 42)
```

The `__str__` method is called automatically when your object is converted to a string, like the `print()` function does.

The `__repr__` method is used for `repr()` representations and when your object is displayed in lists and other containers.

Comment: Thanks that helped but if you don't mind could you tell me how to make my .pop thing going? My program wont pop out the values I want it to instead it will just print everything.

Comment: @Underdog_Nate: You have more than 20 elements in `lst` *already*; you add all entries to `lst` so the `len(lst) < 20` test is never true.